# PIXI.jsのSpriteオブジェクトを手前に表示させたい

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

いくつか個別に作成したSpriteオブジェクトを画面上に表示させました。
画像が重なっている状態です。
クリックまたはスマホの画面タッチでイベントを発生させたいのですが、特定のSpriteオブジェクトを手前に表示させる方法はありますでしょうか。